# executable program loads dynamic library multiple times when observe by strace

Tags: c, mips, strace, uclibc

I have built a complex executable program in MIPS against uCLibc library and many other dynamic shared libraries. This program works fine but it takes over 20 seconds to load, when I observed it by "strace", I found that it keep opening and closing some basic libraries like libm, libc, libgcc, etc. Please, find the log below:

```
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=477720, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=213564, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=477720, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libm.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=96616, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=213564, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=477720, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libdl.so.0", O_RDONLY)       = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=9504, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=213564, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=477720, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=477720, ...}) = 0
close(3)
```

I am sure this continuous open and close action slowed my program down, I tried to create the ld.so.cache under /etc but it does not work, it still needs 20 seconds to load. Anybody has idea? Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: @payne running on MIPS 32 bit

Comment: @payne Linux 3.x kernel